# Attempt to sort pandas df returns multiindex error

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Relatively new to python, I'm trying to use pandas sort_values() to sort my df by a specific column. But I'm getting an error about multiindexing, but I don't think I've created a multiindex have I? Here is the data I'm practicing with. I want to see all data organized by "diggies" in ascending.

> > > df

```
  letters digits diggies
0       A      1          7
1       B      2          3
2       C      3         20
```

> > > df.sort_values(by="diggies")
> > >       ValueError: Cannot sort by column diggies in a multi-index you need to explicitly provide all the levels

Have I unintentionally created a multiindex? Interestingly, I was able to run sort from another practice data set I imported from a CSV. I though the difference might ahve been the data types, but they are both combinations of either "objects" or "int64".

Any tips on why I'm getting this error and how to get around it? Thanks

***added info

> MultiIndex(levels=[['digits', 'letters', 'diggies']],
>              labels=[[1, 0, 2]])

Comment: please show us df.columns

Comment: Just ran df.columns...which does indicate its a multiIndex...why is that and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `get_level_values` to reset the `index`

```
df.columns=df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked...I'll have to read up somemore to understand how I created multiindex in first place and how .get_level_values() works. I apprecaite the quick response.